# Form Validation not working for Select and Checkbox fields Javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, validation, select, checkbox

### Premise:

I'm trying to add form validation using only *JavaScript* and the *DOM* (***without HTML ID tags***).

### Problem:

The first two ***`If`*** statements work, but I'm getting an error for the 3rd and 4th to validate the *`checkbox`* and *`select`* fields.

### Error

> "Cannot read property of undefined"

Suggestions?  Also, how do i `Upvote` or `Accept an answer` here?

Thanks as always :)

### Code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
  <title>Validate me</title>
  <script>
    console.log(document.forms);
    function validateForm() {
      for (var i = 0; i < document.forms[0].length - 1; i++) {
        if (document.forms[0][i].type == 'text' && document.forms[0][i].value == '') {
          alert('Please Enter Your Full Name');
          return false;
        } else if (document.forms[0][i].type == 'radio') {
          if (document.forms[0].gender[0].checked == false && document.forms[0].gender[1].checked == false) {
            alert('Please select gender');
            return false;
          }
        } else if (document.forms[0][i].type == 'checkbox') {
          if (document.forms[0].hobbies[0].checked == false && document.forms[0].hobbies[1].checked == false && document.forms[0].hobbies[2].checked == false) {
            alert('Please select hobby');
            return false;
          }
        } else if (document.forms[0][i].type == 'select') {
          if (document.forms[0].option[0].selected == false && document.forms[0].option[1].selected == false && document.forms[0].option[2].selected == false) {
            alert('Please select a favorite movie')
            return false;
          }
        }
        console.log(document.forms[0][i].type);
      }


    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  At lease one piece of data has to come in from every input type.
  <form action="form.html" method="get"><br/> Name:
    <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter Full Name" /><br/> Gender:
    <br/> Male
    <input type="radio" name="gender" value="male" />Female<input type="radio" name="gender" value="female" /><br/> Hobbies
    <br/> Baseball <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="baseball" /> Football <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="football" /> Hockey <input type="checkbox" name="hobbies[]" value="hockey" /><br/> Favorite Show <select name="show">
    <option value = "">Choose Below</option>
    <option value = "ATHF">Aqua Teen Hunger Force</option>
    <option value = "Family Guy">Family Guy</option>
    <option value = "Simpsons">Simpsons</option>
    </select><br/> Comments
    <br/>
    <textarea cols="50" rows="6" name="comments">Enter Comments</textarea>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" name="submit" value="enter me" onclick="return validateForm();" />
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Select elements do not have type attributes and checkboxes do not have collections on their parent form like radio buttons.

Comment: @Musa ok thanks, I will try a different approach

Comment: @Musa I have corrected the checkbox validation and changed the select to pull by ElementName but the Select validation is still not working.... else if (document.getElementsByName('show').value == ''){
                alert('Please Select a Favorite Show');
                return false;
            }                                                                                                          do you know what i am doing wrong on this one?